# Failed to convert the nvarchar value to int

Tags: sql

I am creating a procedure as follow and when I run it, I get the below error

> An error occurred during client rendering.
>   An error has occurred during report processing.
>   Cannot read the next data row for the dataset dsCitiDriverStats.
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Swedish' to data type int.

The source code of the stored procedure is as follows:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DWReport_CITICallDrivers_Test1]
  @pTransactionsCreatedFrom DATETIME, 
  @pTransactionsCreatedTo DATETIME,
  @pCallerType NVARCHAR(4000),  
  @pCompany NVARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET DATEFIRST 1;

  DECLARE @ComCount int

  SET @ComCount = ( SELECT CAST(LEN(@pCompany) AS int) )
  print @ComCount

  IF @ComCount < 4000
  BEGIN
     SELECT en.ENQ_CREATION_DT AS [Date] ,
         DATEPART(dw, en.ENQ_CREATION_DT) AS WeekDayNo,
         en.ENQ_SOURCE AS CallType,
         CASE enq_caller_type
           WHEN '1389' THEN '3rd'
           WHEN '1390' THEN 'CAS'
           WHEN '1391' THEN 'CH'
           WHEN '1392' THEN 'PA'
           ELSE NULL
         END AS CallerType,
         RIGHT(en.ENQ_CC_NUMBER, 6) AS Last6DigitsOfCardNo,
         en.ENQ_CUSTOMER_NAME AS CustomerName,
         en.ENQ_COMPANY_NAME AS CustomerCompany,
         a.ACCNT_CON_FST_NAME AS LineOfBusiness,
         en.ENQ_ECOUNT_ID AS EcountID,
         lov.Value1 AS [Language],
         en.ENQ_OUTCOME AS ClassificationOfTheCall,
         en.ENQ_COMMENTS_LONG AS Comments,
         en.ENQ_CREATOR_LOGIN AS AgentInitials,
         CASE en.ENQ_CUSTOM_CHK1
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
           ELSE NULL
         END AS VIP
  FROM ENQUIRY                      en 
  JOIN ACCOUNTS                     a   ON a.ACCNT_ID      = en.ENQ_ACCNT_CSN
  JOIN DW_Admin.dw_hold_listofvalue lov ON en.ENQ_LANGUAGE = lov.ID
  WHERE en.ENQ_CREATION_DT >= @pTransactionsCreatedFrom
    AND en.ENQ_CREATION_DT <  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @pTransactionsCreatedTo) + 1, 0)
    AND a.ACCNT_CON_FST_NAME IN ( SELECT s.Item FROM dbo.Split( @pCallerType , ',' ) s )
    AND en.ENQ_COMPANY_NAME  IN ( SELECT s.Item FROM dbo.Split( @pCompany    , ',' ) s )

END  
ELSE
BEGIN

  print 'more than 4K'
  SELECT en.ENQ_CREATION_DT AS [Date],
         DATEPART(dw, en.ENQ_CREATION_DT) AS WeekDayNo,
         en.ENQ_SOURCE AS CallType,
         CASE enq_caller_type
           WHEN '1389' THEN '3rd'
           WHEN '1390' THEN 'CAS'
           WHEN '1391' THEN 'CH'
           WHEN '1392' THEN 'PA'
           ELSE NULL
         END AS CallerType,
         RIGHT(en.ENQ_CC_NUMBER, 6) AS Last6DigitsOfCardNo,
         en.ENQ_CUSTOMER_NAME AS CustomerName,
         en.ENQ_COMPANY_NAME AS CustomerCompany,
         a.ACCNT_CON_FST_NAME AS LineOfBusiness,
         en.ENQ_ECOUNT_ID AS EcountID,
         lov.Value1 AS [Language],
         en.ENQ_OUTCOME AS ClassificationOfTheCall,
         en.ENQ_COMMENTS_LONG AS Comments,
         en.ENQ_CREATOR_LOGIN AS AgentInitials,
         CASE en.ENQ_CUSTOM_CHK1
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
           WHEN 0 THEN 'No'
           ELSE NULL
         END AS VIP
  FROM ENQUIRY                      en 
  JOIN ACCOUNTS                     a   ON a.ACCNT_ID      = en.ENQ_ACCNT_CSN
  JOIN DW_Admin.dw_hold_listofvalue lov ON en.ENQ_LANGUAGE = lov.ID
  WHERE en.ENQ_CREATION_DT >= @pTransactionsCreatedFrom
    AND en.ENQ_CREATION_DT <  DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @pTransactionsCreatedTo) + 1, 0)
    AND a.ACCNT_CON_FST_NAME IN ( SELECT s.Item FROM dbo.Split( @pCallerType , ',' ) s)
    AND en.ENQ_COMPANY_NAME  IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                         COMP_NAME
                                  FROM COMPANIES
                                  WHERE COMP_STATUS = 'Active'
                                )

END

RETURN 0
END
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess since I don't know the content of your database but I think your problem may be here: `ON en.ENQ_LANGUAGE = lov.ID`. I'm guessing that `ENQ_LANGUAGE` is an nvarchar containing 'Swedish' so the comparison to `lov.ID` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

What would you expect to happen when you try to convert the text `Swedish` into an integer? As @devinallenaz pointed out, very likely the table `enquiry`'s column `enq_language` is an `nvarchar` and contains non-numeric data and the failure occurs in trying to convert that to an integer to join against the table `DW_Admin.dw_hold_listofvalue`'s column `id` (likely an integer).

The usual way of sorting out the specifics of the problem is to strip the query down to the minimum thing that works. In you case, comment out all the columns in the result set and replace them with something like `count(*)`. Then comment out the `where` clause in its entirety, along with all the table references in the `from` clause (except the first one).

Run the query. Does it work? If not identify the problem and fix it.

If so, uncomment the next table in the `from` clause. If their is more than one comparison in the join criteria, uncomment only this first one. Run it. Does it work? If so, uncomment the remaining join criteria one at a time. If it still works, repeat the exercise with the next table in the `from` clause.

If you get through the from clause without finding the error, start uncommenting the where clause, one piece at a time.

Once you identify the point of failure, debug it. Run select queries with a `group by` to produce frequency tables of the columns involved. You might want to add a where statement here to remove any data that consists solely of decimal digits. This will likely identify the offending data.

Now you have to decide whether to clean the data (if it's a data problem) or work around it in your query. If you clean the data, you might want to consider putting in guards in your code to prevent junk data from creeping in.

No rocket science involved here. Just old-fashioned police work.

Good luck.